# How to put certain values of json files on the list with Python?

Tags: python, json

```
[
    [
        {
            "indexnum": 677,
            "type": 1,
            "user": 54846,
            "push": 0,
            
        },
        {
            
            "indexnum": 2321,
            "type": 1,
            "user": 77924,
            "push": 0,
            
        }
        
    ]
]

import json


with open('./79553/combined.json', 'r',encoding='UTF-8') as infile:
    my_data = json.load(infile)


datalist1 = []

print(my_data['indexnum'])
```

That is my saved json file and I want to extract only indexnum from that file

and append them in a new list.

(ex. datalist1 = [677,2321,...])

Whether the file was read successfully, all items were outputted normally when I 'print(datalist1)'.

but 'print(my_data['indexnum'])' has 'list indices must be integers or slices, not str' error occured.

How to solve them?

try:

I try my_data[0]['indexnumber']

same problem

Comment: if you print `datalist1` with your code you should get an empty list, since you never append anything to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `my_data` is the whole json:

```json
[
    [
        {
            "indexnum": 677,
            "type": 1,
            "user": 54846,
            "push": 0,
            
        },
        {
            
            "indexnum": 2321,
            "type": 1,
            "user": 77924,
            "push": 0,
            
        }
        
    ]
]
```

This is my_data[0]

```json
[
    {
        "indexnum": 677,
        "type": 1,
        "user": 54846,
        "push": 0,
        
    },
    {
        
        "indexnum": 2321,
        "type": 1,
        "user": 77924,
        "push": 0,
        
    }
    
]
```

This is my_data[0][0]

```json
{
    "indexnum": 677,
    "type": 1,
    "user": 54846,
    "push": 0,
    
}
```

This is my_data[0][0]['indexnum']

```json
677
```

Comment: oh thx my_data[0][0]['indexnum'] is works but my data set has many value so maybe I use for loop like my_data[0][i]['indexnum'] but i don't know how length that json file exactly how to make for loop that?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON format is not uniformly equal bracketed. Either the bracketing is made uniform for the entire file or you access it with the correct list command. my_data[0][0]["indexnum"]

I would highly recommend to use {} brackets througout the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

```
json_data = '''[
    [
        {
            "indexnum": 677,
            "type": 1,
            "user": 54846,
            "push": 0            
        },
        {
            
            "indexnum": 2321,
            "type": 1,
            "user": 77924,
            "push": 0
        }        
    ]
]'''

import json
my_data = json.loads(json_data)
datalist = [x['indexnum'] for x in my_data[0]]
print(datalist)
```

outputs [677, 2321].

But you need to remote trailing commas in lines like `"push": 0,` , because it is not valid JSON this way

Comment: Thank you, but maybe because json is not included directly in the code but reading the file, json.loads gets an error (json.load is possible). Is there any way I can do it if I read the combined.json file like the code?

Answer (score 0):

Your json data is formatted as list nested in list

```
[
    [
        {
            "indexnum": 677,
            "type": 1,
            "user": 54846,
            "push": 0
            
        },
        {
            
            "indexnum": 2321,
            "type": 1,
            "user": 77924,
            "push": 0
            
        }
        
    ]
]
```

Therefore, to get the attribute "indexnum" of the items, you may want to use the double loop after reading the json data

```
import json
import os

with open('./79553/combined.json', 'r',encoding='UTF-8') as infile:
    my_data = json.load(infile)


datalist1 = []
for inner_list in my_data:
    for item in inner_list:
        #only append item has the key "indexnum"
        if item.get("indexnum"):
            datalist1.append(item.get('indexnum'))
```

If you make sure that the first inner list is the only list you have, use this

```
datalist1 = []
for item in my_data[0]:
    #only append item has the key "indexnum"
    if item.get("indexnum"):
        datalist1.append(item.get('indexnum'))
```

or the list comprehensive form

```
datalist1 = [ item.get('indexnum') for item in my_data[0] if item.get('indexnum')]
```